# Scrapy selector doesn't "see" an element that is present on the webpage

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I want to parse the following webpage:
https://mafiaworldtour.com/tournaments/2653

And I need to find the following element:

`//html/body/div[1]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/text()`

When I search it on the webpage via inspect, it is clearly present, but
`city = response.xpath('//html/body/div[1]/div/section[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/text()').extract_first()` returns None.

What is the reason for this?

I expect to get the city `Хайфа, Израиль` of the tournament via xpath.

Comment: You need to retrieve `Хайфа, Израиль` ?

Comment: @GillesQuénotm yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using my own project [retrieveCssOrXpathSelectorFromTextOrNode](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/retrieveCssOrXpathSelectorFromTextOrNode) to fetch the full [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) query:

```
x('Хайфа, Израиль');
//body/div[@class="site-wrapper"]/div[@class="main"][@role="main"]/section[@class="page-content"]/div[@class="container"]/div[@class="tabs"]/div[@class="tab-content"]/div[@class="tab-pane fade in active "][@id="general"]/div[@class="row"]/div[@class="col-md-12"]/div[@class="table-responsive"]/div[@class="responsive-info-table"]/div[@class="row with-top-border"]/div[@class="col-md-6"]/span[@class="small_content"]
```

It's always better to have these specific `XPath` query's than the one with relative path like auto-generated by `chrome dev tools`:

```
//html/body/div[1]/div/section[2]/div/div......
```

But you can remove the useless part, should be like:

(From `chrome dev tools`, or `firefox` console):

```
$x('//span[@class="small_content"]')[0].innerText
```

or in your case:

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="small_content"]/text()').extract_first()
```

##### Output

```
" Хайфа, Израиль"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use both CSS selector orXPATH

**CSS selector**

```
response.css('.small_content::text').get()
```

**XPATH**

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="small_content"]/text()').get()
```